# How can I install sshfs on OSX?

Tags: install, homebrew, ssh

I want to mount remote directories with sshfs. But how can I install it?

Usually I install software with brew. However, in this case it doesn't seem to work:

```
$ brew install sshfs
Error: sshfs has been disabled because it requires closed-source macFUSE!
```

Comment: You don't override it. It is that way on purpose. See https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/1760#discussioncomment-945235

Comment: I'm slightly confused - Are you saying that there is no reason I could possibly want to install sshfs on a Mac, because it depends on a closed source dependency?

Comment: What YOU want, that's up to you.  What the Homebrew devs want, is made plain in that thread.  That thread even offers alternatives, including a third-party tap.

Comment: Hi @Dommondke I think Marc didn’t want to vote to close your question. Lets put it on hold since you are asking a few different questions. Once you have one specific and only one question , Marc can delete this answer if it can’t be edited to fit your need.

Comment: @bmike Thanks for the explanation! The goal of my question is to find a way to install sshfs, doesn't matter whether it's brew or not. I edited the question to make this clearer.

Comment: Nice edits - I’ve cleaned up the comments a bit. If you can’t follow the linked instructions edit in your details and flag for reopening if needed.